# How to retrieve the entire source of search hit in elasticsearch golang client?

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I have an index with too many fields like one docs has 6 fields and other has different number of fields, together there are nearly thousand different fields on total.

i followed this https://github.com/olivere/elastic/wiki/Search, it works fine but i cannot create a struct of all the fields and do `json.Unmarshal(*hit.Source, &t)` on that.
is there any way i can retrieve entire source with out the fields struct.

i use elasticsearch version -7 and olivre elasticsearch golang library.

Comment: "I cannot create a struct of all the fields." Why not? The entire source is obviously stored in hit.Source, JSON encoded. It's not clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: I dont want to unmarshall it against any struct, i just want the json response

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you do not want to unmarshal the json result - you just want access to the value.

The search operation returns a `SearchHit` result [docs here](https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic#SearchHit)

Which has a field

```
type SearchHit struct {
    // trimmed
    Source         json.RawMessage                `json:"_source,omitempty"`         

}
```

A `json.RawMessage` is just a `[]byte`, [docs here](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage).

So to get it as a string, you could do:

```
s := string(hit.Source)
```